# Monitor with 4k, 120hz+, TN, G-Sync?

Tags: gaming, monitors, 4k

I want to upgrade my current monitor, and I'm looking for something future-proof, seeing that a monitor is something that should last a while (10ish years).

The specs mentioned below are what I came up with, and are pretty much non-negotiable. However, I can not seem to find any monitor that meets all of these requirements. There is always something missing.

- 4k resolution
- 120Hz+ refresh rate
- TN panel
- G-Sync enabled

Considering Google search can be tricky when looking for specific things, I might just have overlooked one. Does anyone know of a monitor that meets those specs?

Comment: What dimensions are you looking for, and what's your budget?

Comment: 4k and 120hz dosen't exist yet. DP 1.2 dosen't support it, nor does HDMI 2.0. You're going to likely either wait, or pick one or the other.

Comment: Journeyman Geek is right. The moment 4k/144hz comes out we are gonna hear all about it.

Comment: Why the need for 120hz?  The human eye cannot even detect that can it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't *yet*.

There's high frequency monitors but they seem to top out at 1440p in most cases. Some of them may have gsync.

*All* existing 4k monitors top out at 60hz as far as I know since the 'common' flavours of HDMI (2.0 for TV oriented gear and high end video cards) and DP 1.2) don't have the bandwidth for 4k/UHD and 120hz at the same time.

You'd need to pick one or the other.

Comment: I thought DP 1.3, but not DP 1.2, can support 4k@120Hz. I haven't seen any DP 1.3 monitors or cables, though. Even if those exist, the only monitor that can do 4k@120Hz is that Dell OLED monitor for $5000 that was presented last year, but never made it to the market.

Comment: My bad. I got confused with the version numbers, which is annoying cause I got it right in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The Asus ROG Swift PG27UQ is said to be released in Q3 2017 and satisfies your requirements. It even supports G-Sync HDR. It'll likely cost around $1999 at launch.